# SearchView actionbar changing and search not functioning

Tags: android, android-actionbar, searchview, android-actionbar-compat

I followed [google's tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/search/setup.html) for setting up SearchView for the ActionBar but I encountered a couple of problems. I'm currently testing my app using 2.3.4 and 4.4.2 device.

Problems encountered on my 2.3.4 device

1. ActionBar changes when search button is clicked (search function works)
   [image]
2. When you do a search, it goes to the expected activity but when you press the back button, the layout of ActionBar is changed to the expected layout of ActionBar in problem number 1 but when you do a search now, it wont work.
   [image]

On my 4.4.2 device, there were no problems but as an additional question, how do you collapse the searchview after going back from the search result activity? I want the searchview to be cleared and my actionbar to return to original.

My MainActivity where you can search

```
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            restoreActionBar();

            //From Google tutorial
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                SearchManager searchManager =
                        (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
                SearchView searchView =
                        (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
                searchView.setSearchableInfo(
                        searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
            }
            return true;

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }


 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        } else if (id == R.id.search){

            //From Google tutorial
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            //Removing this will fix problem number 1 but the search function will not work
                onSearchRequested();
            }
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Well, the layout change for lower api devices is not really a big deal but the search function and restoring the actionbar after the result are much more important

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found a fix to this problem. I think the google tutorial is somewhat wrong about supporting the SearchView  below Honeycomb API. According to the tutorial, to enable ActionBar searchview for lower API, you need to add onSearchRequested() in your onOptionsItemSelected(). However, this will result to the problems I encountered above.

getActionView() is the method that isn't compatible with lower APIs and I found MenuItemCompat.getActionView() from compat library which is  which will work for higher and lower APIs. You should now remove onSearchRequested() to prevent further problems and let the getActionView() work for it. As for handling the result, you can do the meta-data method (from Google tutorial which has some missing parts, find another tutorial) or searchView.setOnQueryTextListener().

Here is the fixed code:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        restoreActionBar();

        SearchManager searchManager =
                (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        MenuItem searchItem = (MenuItem) menu.findItem(R.id.search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(
                searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    } 
   //Don't add onSearchRequested() anymore here 

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```